# having output of python in console and html and text

Tags: python, html, text

I wrote the following code using python, I want the output to be in console, text and html 
the problem in html output that in the output below , there are two columns the first one is the key and the other is the value in the console and text there is a space between them but in html there is not any space

```
print f
x = "John"
g = "Peter"


if re.search(x,f) :
    print temp.format("It contains  John",2)
if re.search(g,f):
    print temp.format("It contains  Peter",5)
if re.search(x,f) and re.search(g,f):
    print "It contains both persons"

sys.stdout = save_stdout    
print capture.getvalue()
template = """
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>%(text)s</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""


count = capture.getvalue().count('\n')-1
html_message = template %{"text":capture.getvalue().replace('\n', "<br>\n", count)}


f2.write(html_message+"\n")
f2.close()

f1.write(capture.getvalue())
f1.close()
```

==============================================================================

```
input : "Peter and John went to London"
output in console:
Peter and John went to London
It contains  John       2
It contains  Peter      5
It contains both persons 

but in html:
Peter and John went to London
It contains John 2
It contains Peter 5
It contains both persons
```

in the output of html there isn't a space like in console and text . 
can any one help me with this ?

Comment: HTML requires special care to produce columns. Consoles use fix-width fonts, so columns there are as simple as determining the necessary number of spaces. There are several methods to produce columns in HTML so research that and choose what method best fits your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution - use `<pre>%(text)s</pre>`

`<pre>` shows all spaces, tabs and "\n" (you don't need `<br>`)

---

For one argument you can use

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1: 
   if sys.argv[1] == '--h':
      print "create HTML"
   elif sys.argv[1] == '--t':
      print "create TEXT"
```

For more complicated arguments (install and) use module `getopt` or `argparse`

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: if I want to add something to allow the user to choose like (--h) for help, (--f) .. how could I do that to the code above

Comment: what does argv suppose to be ?? should I use the above in my code as it is ?? because I read about arguments but to be honest I didn't understand

Comment: If you run `python my_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3` you have list `argv=['my_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']`

Comment: I'm really sorry . but python my_script.py what is this ?? is this another code I should write and save it with the name my_script ??

Comment: How do you run your script ? In console ? Writing `python script_name.py` ? How do you want to use `--h`, `--f` ? `python script_name.py --h --f` ?

Comment: You can use arguments like --h and --f only running script directly in console.

Comment: I want to let the user to choose where could he see the output: the default through the console and he can select text file and html

Comment: You can: 1. use arguments like on screenshots. or 2. ask for it in console - using `raw_input()` . or 3. create GUI to ask for it in some window - it needs more work. If you run script like on screenshots you got list in python `argv=['script_name.py', '--h', '--f']` and you can check values on that list.

Comment: just to double check ... if I use arguments like on screen shot, the code you provided me above is it written inside my program . Do you know a simple reference for this ?

Comment: List `argv` (or something similar) is build-in element in Python/C/C++/Java/etc. I don't know reference for it. It is too simple. Even if you don't run script with argument you have `argv` in Python with `['script_name.py']`. Run in Python `print argv`

Comment: Correction: C/C++ has build-in argv, Python needs to `import sys` and then you need use `print sys.argv`